# The if statement looks right but got wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
a = 5
b = 10
if a < 5 and b > 5:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

When running the code above, I expect the answer is Yes. But the output is 'No'. Could anyone please tell me what wrong in my code is? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would it be `Yes`? `5 < 5` is False because 5 is not lower than 5.

Comment: You should learn the difference between strictly less than and less than or equal to... it could save your life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a is assigned to 5
this means that a is equal to five (a < 5 is false)
try doing

```
    if a <= 5 and b >= 5:
        print('yes'
    else:
        print('no')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are expecting `5` to be lower than `5` (`a = 5` and `a < 5`). That's clearly not true, so the expression `a < 5 and b > 5` is False and the `else` branch is picked.